# visual studio code with abstract syntax

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript1.6

How do I use the **abstract** keyword in "Visual Studio Code"?

This was added in the version 1.6 of Typescript, but it doesn't work in Visual Studio Code:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3578

Comment: TypeScript 1.6 isn't out yet.

Comment: They have nighty npms now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to have `abstract` in VSCode today it is possible, though unsupported ;)

What you can do is execute the command `npm install typescript@next` this will fetch a nightly build created by the TypeScript team. You can also build it yourself from the source @github offcourse.

After you have executed the command you have the node_modules folder, we use that later. We use the files from **node_modules\typescript\lib**

Now go to your location where VSCode is, in my case

> C:\Users\dvdbrink\AppData\Local\Code\app-0.3.2\resources\app\plugins\vs.language.typescript\lib

Change the username to yours to get to the correct folder, AppData may be a hidden folder.

Copy the files from your npm install location to the location above and restart code.

Now abstract should work correctly, eg it gives errors when you don't implement it correctly and you get all the squiggles. It just doesn't color the `abstract` keyword!

You might have multiple app-**0.3.2**, I guess you should always have the latest one!

Comment: I will try, soon inform if all went well

Answer (score 1):

<strike>There is no abstract functionality in Typescript 1.6. The link you reference is a closed suggestion for Typescript 1.6.</strike>

Typescript 1.5 is the current latest release of the language.

That said, [you can fake a level of abstract functionality.](http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/typescript-abstract-classes) I would not recommend this though, as it does not seem worth the overhead and there is very little to be gained with using this.

```
export class BaseClass {
    public render() {
        console.log('Base Start');
        this.renderAbstract();
        console.log('Base Start');
    }

    renderAbstract() { throw new Error('This method is abstract and must be overrided.'); }
}

export class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
    public renderAbstract(): void {
        console.log('- Child -');
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I was mistaken, that suggestion is being merged into the Typescript 1.6 build. However, it still hasn't released yet, so you still can't use this functionality *yet*.

Comment: Not entirely true. Abstract classes are [coming TypeScript 1.6](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3579). Additionally, take a look at the [roadmap](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap).

Comment: @DavidSherret Good catch, you are totally right. Thank you.